# How to remove green lines from adobe premiere pro 2020?

Tags: premiere

Please help. I been using premiere pro 2020 for three years and this is the first issue I ever got. I have green lines showing up on my video clips on both sides and surely weren't filmed that way in the first place. They show up in premiere but when I export them, they come out completely fine and run smoothly. Please let me know if you have any tips or answer to get rid of this green lines.

Comment: Does it look like this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/adobe-premiere-pro-green-lines-problem ?
Have tried installing a slightly older version of the graphics driver (not the latest)?

Comment: Yes exactly like that

Comment: what is the older version graphic driver where can I find it?

Comment: Oh, since you don't know how to install a driver, you probably don't have the newest one. Maybe your driver is way too old. Sorry for the confusion, but I can't tell for sure. You need to find out what graphic card model you have and go to the manufacturer's website and download and install a driver. The best is, you first try to install the newest one. If that doesn't help, try an older one, which is 1 or 2 version numbers before that. That's as far as I can help you. If you still need help, contact Adobe support.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically related to your graphics driver, if you were not getting those lines in previous versions then better you to Roll back your graphics driver to old one, or update/wait for newer version to get released, I was having the same issue I tried many things didn't work and I just left hope but after somedays I opened Adobe premier and saw there were no green lines.